# Embed HTML email attatchment in body from access query

Tags: html, email, ms-access, vba

I have a database. It has a form that sends an email, attaching query results to it (the attachment is an HTML document).
My VBA code for the form is:

```
Private Sub button_send_Click()
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, Me!query_name, acFormatTXT, me!email_address, , , "Subject Line"
End Sub
```

I would not like my form to attach the query results. I need it to put the content from the attachment into the main body of the email instead.
Is there a way of doing this with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this to list the output:

```
Public Function ListQuery() As String

    Dim qdy     As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld     As DAO.Field
    Dim List    As String

    Set qdy = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
    qdy.Parameters(0).Value = Forms!NameOfYourForm!NameOfSomeTextbox.Value
    qdy.Parameters(1).Value = Forms!NameOfYourForm!NameOfOtherTextbox.Value
    Set rst = qdy.OpenRecordset()
    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        While Not rst.EOF
            For Each fld In rst.Fields
                List = List & fld.Value & vbTab
            Next
            List = List & vbCrLf
            rst.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    rst.Close

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdy = Nothing

    ListQuery = List

End Function
```

Then:

```
Dim MessageText As String

MessageText = ListQuery
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , acFormatTXT, Me!email_address, , , "Subject Line", MessageText
```

Comment: I have limited knowledge in VBA and access. How would I implement this into my database?

Comment: Copy/paste into a module. Compile and save.

Comment: Replace the _DoCmd_ line.

Comment: When I run the form, I get the error `Run-time error 3061`, `Too few parameters. Expected 2`

Comment: Then your query probably need some parameter values from your form. See edited answer. Replace with names of relevant textboxes.

Comment: What do I put in `NameOfOtherTextbox`?

Comment: You replace that name with the name of your actual textbox or field that holds the parameter for the query.

Comment: My query is a parameter query. The fields are in the query. I have no parameter field in my form at the moment. The only field is what the email address is.

Comment: [Here is my database](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A34EB9B98BE588C9!5400&authkey=!AIblN8qPeLWRvZc&ithint=file%2caccdb)

Comment: Your query asks for two parameters, Key and Quantity. You will have to 1) Modify the code as shown above (which you didn't) 2) Supply the values for the parameters.

Comment: I have done that. It is now not showing me the error and I get to preview and click send, but the message does not arrive. Also, the hyperlinks in the fields in my table do not show up on the email. Any help? Download my database from the comment above.

Comment: Great. However, if the message is created and, in Outlook, you can send it with no error, the issue is beyond your Access application.

Comment: I will ask someone about it on another forum. Thanks for all your help.